# I try to make a Daily Gamble Game however

Tags: mysql, discord.js

I try to get the Highest Number out of my Databse.
So far so good Test 1 Code:

```
const db = require("../../../database.js")
const test = require("./test.js")
module.exports = {
    config: {
      name: "try",
      description: "Replies with a Number.",
    },
    permissions: ['SendMessages'],
    owner: false,
    run: async (client, message, args, prefix) => {
    const test = await db.query("select Number, MemberID from numbers order by Number DESC LIMIT 3;")
    console.log(test[1])
    console.log(test[1].Number)
    }}
```

But all I get out in my Console is:

```
Executing (default): select Number, MemberID from numbers order by Number DESC LIMIT 3;
[ { Number: 138, MemberID: '318735407963439104' } ]
undefined
```

So I tried another Version:

```
const db = require("../../../database.js")
module.exports = {
    config: {
      name: "stats",
      description: "Replies with a Number.",
    },
    permissions: ['SendMessages'],
    owner: false,
    run: async (client, message, args, prefix) => {
  const query = await db.query("select Number, MemberID from numbers order by Number DESC LIMIT 3;", async function (err, result, fields)
    {
        console.log(query)
    const level = result[0].Number
    const user = result[0].MemberID
   const level1 = result[1].Number
    const user1 = result[1].MemberID
  const level2 = result[2].Number1
   const user2 = result[2].MemberID

   console.log(level)
})
    }
};
```

But this just showed this in the Console

```
Executing (default): select Number,MemberID from numbers order by Number DESC LIMIT 3;
```

and nothing else.

I'm really depressed that nothing works, can someone help?

Comment: [Arrays are zero-indexed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), meaning that if you only have one object in your array you will have to use `result[0]`, not `result[1]`.

Comment: Yes I've tried it and it didn't chanced the end result.

Comment: Can you show how your database structured? Because you're calling the column multiple times such as `result[0]` as Number and `result[0]` as MemberID

Comment: My Databse table looks like this: https://srcb.in/oaig7A9U5f